# Sequential Numbering that Resets to 1 Based on Another Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sequential

I would like to create automatic sequential numbering, but I need it to start again at 1 when another column updates. For example: AAA01, AAA02, AAA03, BBB01, BBB02, etc.

As someone who doesn't know how to code, how do I do this?

**Edit: I worked out how to do this. Detailing my (simplified) findings here in case it helps someone else.**

Two tables:

1. Columns: ID (AAA), Result (AAA01)
2. Columns: LastUsedID (AAA), SeqNo (01)

Get items from both tables in Power Automate. Condition to check if first table's ID matches AAA.

- If true, +1 to SeqNo, update SeqNo in Table2, return result in Table1 (e.g., AAA01, AAA02).
- If false, (say it's BBB) update Table2 LastUsedID to BBB, reset SeqNo to 1, return result in Table1 (BBB01).

The only issue is if you intend to go back to using AAA after BBB, because it will reset to 1 and throw errors (assuming you are enforcing unique values). If you need that functionality, you'll need to do more setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flow to update column as following picture shows.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm don't understand how that works? 

I used AAA, BBB as examples, but the actual column is date based and updates monthly (so 2201, 2202 so far this year). Every time it updates I need the number to reset to 01, so I end up with (in a calculated column) 220101, 220102, 220103, then when it updates 220201, 220202...

I know how to do everything but the sequential numbering based on the changing date. Currently it's manual, but I'd like to automate it.